# How to enable Developer Options by default in android source?

Tags: android, android-kernel, android-rom

I want to enable `Developer Options` by default on android source?

Is it possible? Please let me know.

Comment: You mean the phone developer option?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking for?

Answer (score 3):

The default depends on the Android build type.

For `user` or `userdebug` builds, you need to jump through the hoops of tapping the build number seven times.
For `eng` builds, Developer options are enabled by default.

As of Android Q, the codepath lies in [frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/development/DevelopmentSettingsEnabler.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r35/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/development/DevelopmentSettingsEnabler.java#46).

```java
final boolean settingEnabled = Settings.Global.getInt(
        context.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED,
        /* Default if preference not yet set: */
        Build.TYPE.equals("eng") ? 1 : 0) != 0;
```

You can change this to the following:

```java
final boolean settingEnabled = Settings.Global.getInt(
        context.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED,
        1) != 0;
```

...and development settings will be enabled by default, while still allowing you to toggle its enablement on and off in the UI.

For enabling (insecure) ADB connections without approving them beforehand to enable faster early-stage bringups, look into `ro.adb.secure`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what you are asking for. But if your requirement is to enable **Developer Options** on android phone then follow below steps :

1.Open the **Settings** app.

2.select **About phone**

3.Scroll to the bottom and tap **Build number** 7 times.

4.Return to the previous screen to find **Developer options** near the bottom

5.Now, you can toggle the options on and off

Comment: this actually `how to enable developers options` not how to do it programmatically